# XSS formatting in javascript string

Tags: javascript, html, xss

While learning xss I came across a write up on [zseano hackerone ctf](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/xss-playground-zseano-33-stored-writeup-rounak-bania).

The post illustrates embedding an `alert` call inside of the comment section. Forgive any misspeak but my understanding is;

There is an html area in which we will supply the input:

```
<textarea class="form-control rounded-0" id="msgreport" rows="5"></textarea>
```

which is then loaded into the comment via an api call executed by:

```
addComment(document.getElementById('msgreport').value);
```

once the comment is generated a new html div is populated and in it is the following:

```
<script>var commentContent='test'-alert(2)-'hello';</script>
```

The format illustrated in the post:

```
test'-alert(2)-'hello
```

is a little confusing for me. I dissected it further and found that when i use `typeof` it is telling me it is a `number`.

My background is not in web dev so I am a little lost on how exactly this works.
I would think that `test'alert(2)'xss` would work as well, however when I loaded it up -- no dice.

Comment: You can subtract anything in javascript, not only numbers. It will try to convert strings to numbers and if it fails it uses `NaN`

Comment: _"I would think that test'alert(2)'xss would work as well"_ - no, `var commentContent='test'alert(2)'xss';` would just be invalid syntax.

Comment: @CBroe fair enough. could you enlighten me as to why `'test'-alert(2)-'xss ;`. does work? what does `-` do in javascript?

Comment: [Subtracts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Subtraction)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To know final result of `'test'-alert(2)-'hello'` JS tries to evaluate what exactly is returned from `alert(2)`, and there is no other way than just execute that function call.

In JS `'a' - 'b'` is valid, even if that leads to non-number outcome (`NaN`)

```js
console.log('a' - 'b')
```

Keeping that in mind `'a'alert(2)'b'` would be syntax error and will not execute code.

Comment: Ahh. Understood now! Thanks so much.

Wow....yeah big oversight on my part.